# Why do electrons have fixed energy levels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation, orbitals

I understand that electrons do not orbit the nucleus, instead they have a higher probability to be found at some specific regions.

But what makes they appear more frequently in the orbital regions? There are equations (like Schrödinger) that are able to describe this wave function, but what causes it?

Comment: If your question is essentially "why are some things quantised", the answer is we have no idea, that's just things seem to be.

Comment: Are you asking why the probability density is shaped this way? Or are you asking what causes quantization? To the latter there is no known answer.

Comment: I'm asking what causes the probability density to be shaped that way.

Comment: @Charlie, The reason why standing waves are quantized is a plain, mathematical certainty. What we have no idea of is why some (very small) things can be described with wave equations.

Comment: A pedantic point that might be useful at some future time:  electrons don't have energy levels.  Atoms do, and molecules do, and nuclei do, and solids do, ...

Comment: Isnt this because waves about a nucleus only have whole number frequency solutions in order to be stable/not destructively interfere? And those frequencies tell you the energies.

Comment: Please @JKusin can you elaborate more about this destructive interference, I feel this is the closest to an answer.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto I am not certain but ive heard that explanation, maybe it will help your searching. If you picture bending a 2D wave around a circle, if the peaks dont line up from successive windings, they will destructively interfere. So only certain frequencies are stable, and frequency is tied to energy levels. Something analogous

Comment: Makes perfect sense, I can easily visualize this in my head. Thank you a lot @JKusin

Comment: @SolomonSlow yes but electrons are not standing waves, they are just modelled that way.

Comment: @Charlie, I don't understand. I did not say that electrons are standing waves. I said that they, "can be _described_ with wave equations." In other words, we model them that way. The point is, we model them that way because the model _works_. The model completely explains the discrete energy levels. The part where "we have no idea" is, we have no idea _why_ the model works.

Comment: @SolomonSlow sure but that's what I was saying in my original comment. It sounds like we agree on this so theres not much point taking it further.

Answer (score 4):

Nobody knows the answer. All we know is that quantum mechanics is in perfect agreement with experiment. All you can do is to critically investigate any intuitive concepts that you may have that are incompatible with quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that when Richard Feynman was asked what the Schrödinger  equation (SE) was, he replied (paraphrasing from memory): '*it's something that happened in Schrödinger's mind!*'

In truth we don't know why the SE works, only that it does tremendously well!

> I understand that electrons do not orbit the nucleus, instead they
> have a higher probability to be found at some specific regions.

The SE is a second order, linear partial differential equation and quite similar to other important equations like the (Classical) wave equation, diffusion equation and Fourier heat equation.

Like the SE, when these equations act on a bounded domain they become eigenvalue/eigenfunction problems. In Quantum Mechanics we call this quantisation.

In the case of the SE, the bounded wave functions (solutions to the SE) combined with the [Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule) this yields the probability density distributions which tend to be wave-like.

Answer (score 2):

The energy levels of the Hydrogen atom have specific energy levels because the solution of the S-equation says so. Other than this no one knows why things are described by the S-eqn. It just the way things are. The S-eqn provides a mathematical explanation of the way things work. It has been checked against known results and it agrees perfectly so there is little reason to doubt it.